# Dependency Injection by activating IValueCalculator from the book Pro-ASP-Net-MVC-5-Adam-Freeman from Apress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have no experience with Dependency Injection. Someone told me to use the book Pro-ASP-Net-MVC-5-Adam-Freeman from Apress. In chapter 6 I tried the sample but get this message:

Error activating IValueCalculator
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 2) Injection of dependency IValueCalculator into parameter calcParam of constructor of type HomeController
 1) Request for HomeController

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IValueCalculator.
 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

Can somebody tell me what I need to change? It is important to understand the other chapters.

I found some information about this issue, but it wasn't helpful for me.

Link to the source code: http://www.apress.com/9781430265290

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have registered the dependency injection in the App_Start folder.

```
    private void AddBindings()
    {
       kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<ClassNameWhereIValueCalcultorIs
               Used>();
    }
```